# использовать django-filter во ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Как можно использовать `django-filter` во `viewsets.ViewSet`? (использовать `modelViewSet` или `ApiView` итд нельзя)
Что нужно переопределить/изменить?
Я понимаю что `ViewSet` дает все писать с нуля, `CRUD` у меня на нем получилось сделать без проблем, а вот прикрутить фильтрацию без `ModelViewSet` вообще не получается.
Фильтрация по многим параметрам в том числе и с вычислениями, `djanfo-filter` с этим справляется(уже проверено) но не работает на `ViewSet` :(
Вот как я себе это представляю:

```
class MortgageViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    """ 
        # C этим кодом и ModelsViewSet работает как надо, но нужно юзать просто ViewSet
        queryset = Mortgage.objects.all()
        serializer_class = FiltersSerializer
        filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
        filterset_class = ProductFilter
        filterset_fields = ('__all__')
    """


    def list(self, request):
        if len(self.request.query_params) <= 0:
            #Если url не содержит параметров - возвращаем НЕ фильтрованный кверисет
        else:
            #Если в url хоть 1 параметр есть - возвращаем фильтрованный кверисет
```

Можно ли из функции заставить работать `filterset_class` например как в `ModelViewSet`? Если да - как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

в [документации](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/install.html) должно быть описано

думаю можно попробовать определить класс фильтра и использовать его в view

```py
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class MortgageViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        filte = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
        ...
```

Comment: я уже пытался добавить так... но мне дает ошибку 
TypeError: 'ProductFilter' object is not iterable

Comment: в какой момент при вызове `filte = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())` ?